# (certbot) How to fix Failed authorization procedure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ssl, certbot

I am running Ubuntu 18.04  with nginx and I am getting the following error when I try to generate a ssl certificate for my server using certbot:

> Failed authorization procedure. irfreeman.ubuviz.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: No valid IP addresses found for irfreeman.ubuviz.com, [www.irfreeman.ubuviz.com](http://www.irfreeman.ubuviz.com) (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: No valid IP addresses found for [www.irfreeman.ubuviz.com](http://www.irfreeman.ubuviz.com)
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>
> The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: irfreeman.ubuviz.com
>
> Type:   None
>
> Detail: No valid IP addresses found for irfreeman.ubuviz.com
>
> Domain: [www.irfreeman.ubuviz.com](http://www.irfreeman.ubuviz.com)
>
> Type:   None
>
> Detail: No valid IP addresses found for [www.irfreeman.ubuviz.com](http://www.irfreeman.ubuviz.com)

I would like to know if the problem comes from maybe a bad configuration or any other error.

If I try to deduct from this, I might think that there are no subdomain named irfree.ubuviz.com but I am pretty sure there is one.

Comment: What did you put in your DNS records?

Comment: You may  be sure but you're wrong. According to the authoritative DNS server for ubuvis.com at pete.ns.cloudflare.com, neither www.irfreeman.ubuviz.com nor irfree.ubuviz.com (which are not at all the same thing) exists.